# Is Ubuntu OS 18.04.4 LTS is free (open source) version for use?

Tags: software-installation

I can see on Ubuntu website that its an open-source software, free to use.
Though i would like to know if all Ubuntu OS versions are free to use ?
Example 18.04.4 LTS ?
What does LTS actually mean in it ?

Thankyou

Comment: These seem like common, generic questions that are readily answered by most Search Engines.

Comment: I opened a search engine (startpage) & entered "*LTS means*" as my search,t he first five answers told me the answer, and included https://ubuntu.com/blog/what-is-an-ubuntu-lts-release which I'd treat as an authority advice site given it's from ubuntu.com (more so than wikipedia & other entries in the top 5, but 2 of the top 5 were official ubuntu resources anyway).  Did you try a search engine?  and if it didn't provide you an answer, you have something to fix...

Answer (score 3):

All Ubuntu releases have the same license. You can use them for free.

LTS means Long Term Support with 5-year support.

Comment: Just add for more info, other releases/versions have only 9 months of support, like 18.10 19.04, 19.10.

Comment: Flavors also don't come with 5 years of support; standard support for *flavors* is three years for LTS (they never extended to 5 years like main Ubuntu did), and whilst the Ubuntu base still does get security upgrades/patches, this will only protect part of the system.  5 years applies to 'main' repository packages only, or packages on the installation media with very few exceptions.